# how to create a function that lets you pass parameters

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that includes date and country name and I wanted to know how this could be created into a function so that a date rate ie, between 2000-01-01 and 2001-12-31, and a country name like 'germany' could be passed as variables.

I have created a query but not the function.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers c
Join Orders o
On c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '2017-01-01'
AND c.Country LIKE 'Germany'
```

is it possible to have parameters for date range and for country, so that those can be passed in a function?

Comment: Please study how stored procedures work. What you desire is entirely possible.

Comment: @Bleep-Bloop Absolutely a sproc, I doubt a function would be needed here.

Comment: @Bleep-Bloop Give a man a fish vs teach a man to fish? Stored procedures are more general, I expect the OP will eventually come across functions too and the distinction between them.

Comment: Hi, I know how to do this as a procedure, I asked about function since it was something we were asked to try as well as the procedure, I just needed a bit of help understanding it.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an [inline table valued function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#b-creating-an-inline-table-valued-function), e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCustomerOrders(@Country VARCHAR(255), @DateFrom DATE, @DateTo DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(   SELECT  c.CustomerID,
            o.OrderDate,
            c.Country,
            <Other Fields>
    FROM    dbo.Customers AS c
            INNER JOIN dbo.Orders AS o
                ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    WHERE   o.OrderDate >= @DateFrom
    AND     o.OrderDate <= @DateTo
    AND     c.Country = @Country
);
```

You would then use this as:

```
SELECT  <columns>
FROM    dbo.GetCustomerOrders('Germany', '19000101', '20170101') AS co;
```

Or, if you need to use another table as your parameter source you would use:

```
SELECT  <columns>
FROM    dbo.SomeOtherTable AS t
        CROSS APPLY dbo.GetCustomerOrders(t.Country, t.StartDate, t.EndDate) AS co;
```

The latter usage is a good demonstration of why a table valued function is a better idea than a stored procedure if you want to encapsulate a simple select. It is just as re-usable, but more versatile. They tend to perform better too, as the query definition of the function is expanded into the outer query, so you are more likely to get an optimal execution plan depending on your use case.

I have changed `BETWEEN` to `>= AND <=` - although this is semantically the same, I find between can cause issues, especially if you are querying a datetime column. Further reading: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common). If `OrderDate` is a datetime column, you may find the following more appropriate:

```
WHERE   o.OrderDate >= @DateFrom
AND     o.OrderDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateTo)
```

I have also explicitly listed your columns (whee I can) as you should never use `SELECT *` in production code. Further reading: [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). I also include the `dbo.` schema prefix, as it [generally a good idea to do so](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) (unless you are intentionally leaving this off so that the tables referenced will vary depending on login, which I suspect you are not)

Finally, I have changed `LIKE` to `=` since you are not doing any wildcard or pattern matching.

If you wanted a stored procedure, the syntax would be

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetCustomerOrders (@Country VARCHAR(255), @DateFrom DATE, @DateTo DATE)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  c.CustomerID,
            o.OrderDate,
            c.Country,
            <Other Fields>
    FROM    dbo.Customers AS c
            INNER JOIN dbo.Orders AS o
                ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    WHERE   o.OrderDate >= @DateFrom
    AND     o.OrderDate <= @DateTo
    AND     c.Country = @Country;
END
```

And this would be called using:

```
EXECUTE dbo.GetCustomerOrders('Germany', '19000101', '20170101');
```

But as above, for a simple select I don't think this offers any advantages over a TVF, only disadvantages.

<sub>As one final point, I have no affiliation with SQL Blog, or Aaron Bertrand, I am not intentionally plugging loads of his blogs, it is just that they are all very relevant.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This creates an inline table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CustomerOrders (
    @FromDate DATE,
    @ToDate DATE,
    @CountryLike VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS TABLE AS 
RETURN
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        Customers c
        inner Join Orders o On c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    WHERE 
        o.OrderDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND 
        c.Country LIKE '%' + @CountryLike + '%'
```

Please avoid using `*`, replace with the actual columns you plan on using. Also note that I added both wildcard characters directly inside the function so you don't have to write `%` on the country name (you can change it to fit your needs).

You use it like the following:

```
SELECT
    C.*
FROM
    dbo.CustomerOrders('2019-05-01', '2019-06-15', 'German') AS C
```